# What is wrong with this rss feed?

Tags: xml, rss, syntax-error, validation

Here is an rss feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss version="2.0"><channel><title>Porthmadog Tide Times</title><link>http://port-tides.com</link><description>Free tidal predictions for Porthmadog</description><item><title>Porthmadog Tide Times</title><link>http://port-tides.com</link><description>Free tidal predictions for Porthmadog</description><content:encoded><![CDATA[<html><head><style>h3{    padding: 0px;    margin: 0px;}</style></head><body><center><h3>Today</h3><p>07:54 (4.60m)<br/>20:19 (5.00m)<p><h3>Sunday</h3><p>08:45 (5.00m)<br/>21:07 (5.40m)<p><h3>Monday</h3><p>09:33 (5.30m)<br/>21:53 (5.70m)<p><h3>Tuesday</h3><p>10:17 (5.50m)<br/>22:38 (5.80m)<p><h3>Wednesday</h3><p>10:59 (5.50m)<br/>23:21 (5.70m)<p><h3>Thursday</h3><p>11:45 (5.30m)<br/><p><h3>Friday</h3><p>00:09 (5.40m)<br/>12:31 (5.00m)<p></center></body></html>]></content><link>http://port-tides.com</link></channel></rss>
```

The code validator at http://validator.w3.org/feed/ says this:

> `This feed does not validate. line 1, column 327: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:341: unbound prefix`

Answer (score 0):

You have `<content:encoded>` but you don't have `xmlns:content="http://some.namespace.example.com"` anywhere.